# How do I check if animation is of Animation Type "Humanoid"?

Tags: unity, animation

One can set the Rig / Animation type of an animation to "Generic", "Humanoid", etc.

[image: Screenshot showing animation rig types]

How could I check by script if an animation rig has been set to type "Humanoid"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody from Unity answered this question to me:

```
You can check AnimationType in script using Asset Import PostProcessor: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor-assetImporter.html

Here is the code showcasing how you would access the AnimationType:

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class CustomImportSettings : AssetPostprocessor
{
    void OnPreprocessModel()
    {
        ModelImporter importer = (ModelImporter)assetImporter;
        ModelImporterAnimationType type = importer.animationType;
    }
}
```